# How to Fill an array from user input C#?

Tags: c#

What would be the best way to fill an array from user input?

Would a solution be showing a prompt message and then get the values from from the user?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
string []answer = new string[10];
for(int i = 0;i<answer.length;i++)
{
    answer[i]= Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Could you clarify the question a bit?  Are you trying to get a fixed number of answers from the user?  What data type do you expect -- text, integers, floating-point decimal numbers?  That makes a big difference.

If you wanted, for instance, an array of integers, you could ask the user to enter them separated by spaces or commas, then use

```
string foo = Console.ReadLine();
string[] tokens = foo.Split(",");
List<int> nums = new List<int>();
int oneNum;
foreach(string s in tokens)
{
    if(Int32.TryParse(s, out oneNum))
        nums.Add(oneNum);
}
```

Of course, you don't necessarily have to go the extra step of converting to ints, but I thought it might help to show how you would.

Comment: after showing the user a msg to input the elements(6 floating numbers) I want the user to input the elements separeated by commas

so at first i decleared the array
double[] array;
array = new double[6];

now i need to read the elements

Comment: Your line `string[] tokens = foo.Split(",");` should be `string[] tokens = foo.Split(',');` Note the double quotes changed to single quotes.

Comment: I got your code and My Example is solved but I can't understand your if statement. Please explain me it

Answer (score 4):

It made a lot more sense to add this as an answer to [arin's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230454/how-to-fill-an-array-from-user-input-c#231047) than to keep doing it in comments...

1) Consider using decimal instead of double. It's more likely to give the answer the user expects. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/floatingpoint.html and http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/decimal.html for reasons why. Basically decimal works a lot closer to how humans think about numbers than double does. Double works more like how computers "naturally" think about numbers, which is why it's faster - but that's not relevant here.

2) For user input, it's usually worth using a method which doesn't throw an exception on bad input - e.g. decimal.TryParse and int.TryParse. These return a Boolean value to say whether or not the parse succeeded, and use an `out` parameter to give the result. If you haven't started learning about `out` parameters yet, it might be worth ignoring this point for the moment.

3) It's only a little point, but I think it's wise to have braces round all "for"/"if" (etc) bodies, so I'd change this:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < 6; counter++)
    Console.WriteLine("{0,5}{1,8}", counter, array[counter]);
```

to this:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < 6; counter++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0,5}{1,8}", counter, array[counter]);
}
```

It makes the block clearer, and means you don't accidentally write:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < 6; counter++)
    Console.WriteLine("{0,5}{1,8}", counter, array[counter]);
    Console.WriteLine("----"); // This isn't part of the for loop!
```

4) Your switch statement doesn't have a `default` case - so if the user types anything other than "yes" or "no" it will just ignore them and quit. You might want to have something like:

```
bool keepGoing = true;
while (keepGoing)
{
    switch (answer)
    {
        case "yes":
            Console.WriteLine("===============================================");
            Console.WriteLine("please enter the array index you wish to get the value of it");
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("===============================================");
            Console.WriteLine("The Value of the selected index is:");
            Console.WriteLine(array[index]);
            keepGoing = false;
            break;

        case "no":
            Console.WriteLine("===============================================");
            Console.WriteLine("HAVE A NICE DAY SIR");
            keepGoing = false;
            break;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, I didn't understand that. Please enter yes or no");
            break;
    }
}
```

5) When you've started learning about LINQ, you might want to come back to this and replace your for loop which sums the input as just:

```
// Or decimal, of course, if you've made the earlier selected change
double sum = input.Sum();
```

Again, this is fairly advanced - don't worry about it for now!

Answer (score 2):

C# does not have a message box that will gather input, but you can use the Visual Basic input box instead.

If you add a reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic .NET Runtime" and then insert:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
```

You can do the following:

```
List<string> responses = new List<string>();
string response = "";

while(!(response = Interaction.InputBox("Please enter your information",
                                        "Window Title",
                                        "Default Text",
                                        xPosition,
                                        yPosition)).equals(""))
{
   responses.Add(response);
}

responses.ToArray();
```

Comment: 0 
 
 No, I didnt mean a message box . i meant when I'm showing a msg

console.writeline("enter the elements of the array");

so what i dont know how to do is how to take the series of inputs from the user using a for loop

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
array[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.Readline());
```

You might also want to use double.TryParse() to make sure that the user didn't enter bogus text and handle that somehow.

Answer (score 2):

## I've done it finaly check it and if there is a better way tell me guys

```
    static void Main()
    {
        double[] array = new double[6];
        Console.WriteLine("Please Sir Enter 6 Floating numbers");
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            array[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        double sum = 0;

        foreach (double d in array)
        {
            sum += d;
        }
        double average = sum / 6;
        Console.WriteLine("===============================================");
        Console.WriteLine("The Values you've entered are");
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1,8}", "index", "value");
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 6; counter++)
            Console.WriteLine("{0,5}{1,8}", counter, array[counter]);
        Console.WriteLine("===============================================");
        Console.WriteLine("The average is ;");
        Console.WriteLine(average);
        Console.WriteLine("===============================================");
        Console.WriteLine("would you like to search for a certain elemnt ? (enter yes or no)");
        string answer = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (answer)
        {
            case "yes":
                Console.WriteLine("===============================================");
                Console.WriteLine("please enter the array index you wish to get the value of it");
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("===============================================");
                Console.WriteLine("The Value of the selected index is:");
                Console.WriteLine(array[index]);
                break;

            case "no":
                Console.WriteLine("===============================================");
                Console.WriteLine("HAVE A NICE DAY SIR");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Congratulations for persevering :) I've edited the post *just* for the formatting of the first few lines, but left all the rest in place. Will add another comment in a sec with a few suggested changes.

Comment: Added a different answer instead - easier to express myself.

Comment: This is the best ever!  It really helped me in a tight bunch.  I made one small change.  Put the Console.WriteLine("Please Sir Enter 6 Floating numbers"); inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Add the input values to a List and when you are done use List.ToArray() to get an array with the values.

Answer (score 0):

of course....Console.ReadLine always return string....so you have to convert type string to double

array[i]=double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Answer (score 0):

readline is for string..
just use read