# Hold integer inputs into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, console, integer

I am trying to hold integer inputs into an array but it doesn't work. I found an example for string hold from [How to Fill an array from user input C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230454/how-to-fill-an-array-from-user-input-c)

```
string[] yazi = new string[15];
for (int i = 0; i < yazi.Length; i++)
{
      yazi[i] = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

But when I turn this code to integer, it gave an error

```
int[] sayis = new int[20];
for (int k = 0; k < sayis.Length; k++)
{
      sayis[k] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Works fine for me as long as I enter integers. What error do you get?

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I miss something?

The error message, for one thing...

It should be fine - so long as you type integers into the console. (I've just tried it, and it worked perfectly.) If the user enters a value which *can't* be parsed as an integer, you'll get a `FormatException`. You should consider using [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) instead... that will set the value in an `out` parameter, and return whether or not it actually succeeded. For example:

```
for (int k = 0; k < sayis.Length; k++)
{
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!int.TryParse(line, out sayis[k]))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Couldn't parse {0} - please enter integers", line);
        k--; // Go round again for this index
    }
}
```

Comment: But I got the error, which I didnt give any input to the console. I mean, I get error when the console run. I will try int.TryParse

Comment: @Merve: Right. That will happen if you don't type in a number (including if you press return without entering anything).