# c# assigning user inputs to arrays with loops

Tags: c#, arrays

Hello guys I recently started an activity that just pooped in to my mind.
I decided to assign user inputs to arrays like this

```
while (true) 
{                  
    int n = 0;
    int[] series = new int[n];

    Console.WriteLine("Please pick a number between 1 and 100:");
    series[n] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
    // This block above creates errors saying it created an unhandled exception. 
    // I havent added a try and catch since this is just a trial a 
    // planned to add them once this program is working

    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to try again (Y/N): ");
    char tryagain = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
    char.ToLower(tryagain);

    if (tryagain == 'y') 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= series.Length; i++) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your numbers are {0}", series[n]);
        }
        break;
    }
    else 
    {
        n = n + 1;
    }
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Thank you in advance and any help is appreciated.

Comment: string such as "1 2 3" can't be converted into array of int's using `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` because it's not a valid int

Comment: `int[] series = new int[n];` this is also creating a 0-length array, since `n` is `0`

Comment: What is your *question*?

Comment: why you declare it as an array if it is for handling one element?

Comment: No i wanted the program to gather as many array elements as possible then display them so i put it inside an infinite while loop. The problem is that my IDE says that this generates an unhandled exception.

Comment: @SanchezMelchor my snippet will parse multiple numbers from string into int array, so it is something you're describing

Comment: If you need debugging help - please provide exact errors/exceptions. Additionally please make sure to search for similar problems - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+read+array+console and see if someone come up with solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230454/how-to-fill-an-array-from-user-input-c

Answer (score 1):

In your code  int[] series = new int[n]; this is also creating a 0-length array. so try this..

```
int n = 1;
int[] series = new int[n];

Console.WriteLine("Please pick a number between 1 and 100:");
series[n-1] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // set value for zero index
```

**UPDATED**

Array length can't be increase runtime. So you can use list<>

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var series = new List<int>();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please pick a number between 1 and 100:");
            series.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to try again (Y/N): ");
            if (Console.ReadLine().ToLower()[0] != 'y')
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Your numbers are:");
        foreach (var number in series)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: but why are you creating array of size 1? It will work only for array with one element? Isn't int variable more suitable for this solution? It doesn't make sense at all

Comment: thats why i added a loop to increase the size of the array as long as the user inputs y.

Comment: @SanchezMelchor Array length can't be increase runtime. so you can use list<>. see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way:

```
var series = new List<int>();
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please pick a number between 1 and 100:");
    series.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to try again (Y/N): ");
    if (Console.ReadLine().ToLower()[0] != 'y')
    {
        break;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Your numbers are:");
foreach (var number in series)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```